# Finding entries NOT starting with vowels in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Basically I want to get those entries which don't start in vowels

So, I tried

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou]'
```

This seems to work. So is it okay to use `^[^aeiou]` to get the required thing.
Or is there any better way?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: There wa some system issue..works properly and thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's fine.  As Strawberry notes, you could move the negation out of the regex if you felt it was more readable, but that won't change anything fundamental.